# Multiple Find & Replace in TexStudio using Script Macros

Tags: macros, texstudio, scripts

I am using TexStudio with MikTex. I am using at least two packages regularly to create certain lists. Let us say, in one package I have to use `\begin{exam}` and `\end{exam}` to start and end list and  `\item` to create list items. In another package, `\begin{test}` and `\end{test}` along with `\choice` to do the same. There are some other similar commands which are different. The subject matter (contents of items) in both is exactly the same. 
I am using `Find and Replace` to convert one to another. It takes time to do it carefully, some replacements need to be done *whole word* some *case sensitive* and so on.

**Question**: Is there a way to use Macros with Script in TexStudio to create a Macro which can work for the whole document and do all replacements in one go?

**Attempts**:  In TexStudio user manual at [TexStudio Manual](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) it mentions 
[image]

I have tried using `editor.replace("\item","\choice")` but didn't work. I don't know if I am following syntax correctly or not, and what to put in *Abbreviation* and *Trigger*.

[image]

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paste this under "LaTeX content":

```
%SCRIPT
options = "g"
scope = editor.document().cursor(0, 0, -1);
editor.replace("\\item",options,scope,"\\choice")
```

Note that the backslash `\` needs to be escaped (i.e., typed twice), if not, the script searches for the word `item` instead, and not `\item`. This then has the undesired effect of changing `item`s in your normal paragraphs to `\choice`s, and also, `\begin{itemize}` to `\begin{choiceize}`, for example.

The `g` stands for global, omit it if you want the macro to only search and replace one `\item` at every call of the macro.

I should note that this is a very crude way of searching and replacing (are you sure you want to change all `\items` to `\choice`?) More sophisticated replacements are possible (e.g. by limiting the scope with the `scope` variable: currently it searches the *entire* document), but then you would have to describe your use case more precisely (and provide an example for me to test with).

Abbreviations and Trigger can be left empty in your case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have added more lines and it is working perfectly fine. For example  `editor.replace("\\begin{exam}",options,scope,"\\begin{test}")`  and also had to delete some code which was occupying whole line so initially I replaced it with _blank_ but that started giving error as it was inside list environment. Now I have replaced them like this `editor.replace("\\stlist",options,scope,"\%\\stlist")`. The good thing is, now I can go back to original document using a reversal of this _script_ and it is working.