# Find and Replace Macro for TeXStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, find

I am using TeXstudio with TeX Live. I am trying to typeset a document that I have converted from an ePub to a LaTeX document using Pandoc. The problem I now face is that, in the ePub, the creator, I believe, has inserted a command to make each page distinct; for in LaTeX, there is now a command that ‘pops up’, e.g.:

`\protect\hypertarget{part00XX.htmlux5cux23page_YY}{}{}`

where XX is the part number, and YY the page number.

As this document has two hundred odd pages, I would prefer not to manually replace each occurrence of this command. To that extent, I have attempted to write a Macro that would search the document and replace any such occurrence (do note that this is my first dabbling in writing macros, the following one is modified from [Multiple Find & Replace in TexStudio using Script Macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419781/multiple-find-replace-in-texstudio-using-script-macros)):

```
%SCRIPT
options = "g"
scope = editor.document().cursor(0, 0, -1);
editor.replace("\\protect\\hypertarget\{part(\d).htmlux5cux23page_(\d)\}\{\}\{\}",options,scope,"")
```

When I trialled this with an actual number instead of the `(\d)`, it worked; however, when I have added in the  `(\d)`, it does not.

How can I make this macro universal across the document such that I can remove all of the ‘page numbering’ commands? Or is there a better way to approach this?

**Question answered**

Thank you all for your comments. I did not realise that a regex could be used in the find and replace.

I copied the recommended script from your comment Frabjous, and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Why don't you search for "\protect\hypertarget" and replace it by  "%\protect\hypertarget" for all? (I.e. commenting it out) // If it doesn't work with your editor, copy to and replace for all using a more suitable one, like Notepad++ or similar, and paste back.

Comment: `\d` is a LaTeX macro which places a dot under its argument. E.g., `\d u` places a dot under `u`.

Comment: surely in any editor that is a simple regex replace that does not need any special scripting, just replace `\\protect\\hypertarget{part[^{}]*}{}{}` by nothing.

Comment: `\d` is a single digit you probably meant `\d+` for a string of digits, but no need to be so specific `[^{}]` (anything that is not a brace) would be fine

Comment: In TeXstudio control-D will open the Find and Replace dialog.

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be a script rather than just running "Replace All" once? Hit Ctrl-R for replace. Click the "Reg" button for regex. Use a pattern such as `\\protect\\hypertarget{part[^{}]*\.html[^{}]*page[^{}]*}{}{}` for "Find", leave "Replace" blank and hit the double down red arrow for "Replace All".